# VS2019 ASP.NET MVC "Cannot navigate to the symbol under caret"

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2019

When opening an existing ASP.NET MVC project inside Visual Studio 2019 I keep receiving this error message "Cannot navigate to the symbol under caret" when trying to "Go To Definition" (F12).

[image]

Answer (score 13, accepted):

None of the other answers on here for "Cannot navigate to the symbol under caret" solved my issue until I found this solution from the visual studio developer community.

Here is the link and bellow is the solution from the post: https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/505489/cannot-navigate-to-the-symbol-under-the-caret-3.html

> This is happening to projects that are using v1.0.0 of 
>   Microsoft.Net.Compilers. To work around this problem you need to
>   update to the latest stable version which is 3.0.0. To do that you can
>   follow the these steps:
>
> 1) Right click on "References" in the Solution Explorer
>
> 2) Select "Manage NuGet Packages"
>
> 3) Under the "Installed" tab search fro "Microsoft.Net.Compilers"
>
> 4) Select "Microsoft.Net.Compilers"
>
> 5) On the side window of "Microsoft.Net.Compilers" click the update button
>
> That should allow you navigate to definitions

Comment: Please make sure the environment that you are running your application can handle this change.