# Cannot navigate to the symbol under the caret - Visual Studio 2015,2017 and 2019

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio, solution

I have been searching for a solution to this for the last 3 days. Please help.

I have tried opening my solution in VS 2015,17 and 19 and whenever I try to go to my namespace I get the error

"cannot navigate to the symbol under the caret"

None of these have helped me.

Failed : [VS2019 ASP.NET MVC "Cannot navigate to the symbol under caret"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55737784/vs2019-asp-net-mvc-cannot-navigate-to-the-symbol-under-caret)

Failed : https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/505489/cannot-navigate-to-the-symbol-under-the-caret-3.html

I have also deleted my .vs folder, didn't work, someone also said delete your .user folder. But there isn't a .user folder in my project.

I also searched for the dot net compilers and found an update but the update made no difference.

It's only on my visual studio. Other people are not having this issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So Installing Resharper fixed my problem after I reloaded the solution in my Visual studio with Resharper installed.

https://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/

I used the trial version.

**Note**: It took a second to load though so make sure resharper has analyzed your files. You should see a progress bar at the bottom right of your Visual Studio when you restart your Visual Studio and open your solution.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem some time ago, and the solution was to create a solution in visual studio with a new MVC project, and then add the source code files to the new project.

Comment: Granted this might solve the problem but it's more of a hack. I don't have the option of creating a new project. I am working on a very big project. I need to fix what is broken

Answer (score 0):

Closed Visual Studio, then deleted ".vs" folder in the solution folder